# Not sure how to make this happen.. 4 sections of text spread evenly across page?

Tags: html, css, text, tabular

I have 4 small bodies of text that I'd like to display evenly across the page. 
Here's an image of what I have in mind:

[image: ideal]

Something tells me tables would be the best way to go, but a)I've always been told not to use them and b) because of that, I have no idea how to do so if that is in fact the best route to take.

I'm open to suggestions; any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: make divs with float and fixed width.

Comment: Use a div element for each block, set the `width` and `height` to something like `25%` and `10em`, respectively and then set the display to `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this would work:

#### CSS:

```
html, body 
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: none;
}
div.content
{
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 25%;
 }
```

#### HTML:

```
<div class="content">Blah</div><div class="content">blah blah</div>
<div class="content">Blah Blah</div><div class="content">blah blah blah blah</div>
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plowdawg/5FSDZ/)

Comment: Use a value of `24%` instead of `25%`, since `25%` of `101px` is `25.25px`, which will be rendered as `26px` resulting in `4 * 26px = 104px`.

Comment: Be careful with inline-block, as there are some [IE combatibility issues](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) with older versions

Comment: @Ben Roux float: left seems to work better.  I've updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Travis's is good, this version gives you a little more to work with, and will let you dial in the padding between the blocks. The background colors are just in there for you to see how it's working.

CSS:

```
.testimonials {
border:1px solid black;
}
.testimonial {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.testimonial blockqoute {
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:yellow;
    font-style:italic;
}
.testimonial attr {
    display:block;
    font-style:normal;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="testimonials">
    <h3>Client Testimonials</h3>
    <div class="testimonial">
        <blockqoute>Blah blah...
            <attr>John Smith <br/>
                boomboom.com</attr>
        </blockqoute>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial">
        <blockqoute>Blah blah...
            <attr>John Smith <br/>
                boomboom.com</attr>
        </blockqoute>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial">
        <blockqoute>Blah blah...
            <attr>John Smith <br/>
                boomboom.com</attr>
        </blockqoute>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial">
        <blockqoute>Blah blah...
            <attr>John Smith <br/>
                boomboom.com</attr>
        </blockqoute>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="content">
<h1>title</h1>
<div class="text_tontent">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<div class="text_tontent">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<div class="text_tontent">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<div class="text_tontent">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
'#content {width:100%; overflow:auto; padding:20px 0}<br />
.text_tontent {width:25%; float:left;}<br />
.text_tontent p {padding:0 10px;}<br />'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Just replace the percentages with pixels if you don't want a liquid layout.

CSS:

```
* {
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
}

#container {
   width: 80%; 
   margin: 0px auto;
}
#container div {
   width: 25%; /* 25% percent of the #container width */
   padding: 10px; 
   float: left
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div>Content 1</div>
  <div>Content 2</div>
  <div>Content 3</div>
  <div>Content 4</div>
</div>
```